# Crear columna a partir de otra columna que en la que cada fila indica la columna a usar para obtener esa celda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Poseo la siguiente información en un DataFrame en Python:

```
##    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   colum
##0  206  214  021  122  554     2
##1  226  234  123  456  789     4
##2  245  253  558  855  123     5
##3  265  272  000  111  222     4
##4  283  291  214  589  996     1
```

y requiero generar una nueva columna dependiendo del valor que contenga la columna `colum`, de la siguiente manera:

```py
##    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   colum   newColum
##0  206  214  021  122  554     2       214
##1  226  234  123  456  789     4       456
##2  245  253  558  855  123     5       123
##3  265  272  000  111  222     4       111
##4  283  291  214  589  996     1       283
```

no se si soy claro en mi solicitud, agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame.apply` sobre las filas (eje 1) obteniendo el nombre de la columna mediante formateo de cadenas simplemente:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
 ##   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   colum
##0  206  214  021  122  554       2
##1  226  234  123  456  789       4
##2  245  253  558  855  123       5
##3  265  272  000  111  222       4
##4  283  291  214  589  996       1
""")

df = pd.read_table(data, sep="\s+", engine="python",  index_col=0)
df["newColum"] = df.apply(lambda row: row[f'x{row["colum"]}'],  axis=1)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>       x1   x2   x3   x4   x5  colum  newColum
> ##                                           
> ##0  206  214   21  122  554      2       214
> ##1  226  234  123  456  789      4       456
> ##2  245  253  558  855  123      5       123
> ##3  265  272    0  111  222      4       111
> ##4  283  291  214  589  996      1       283
> ```

Si cabe la psoibilidad de que existan valores en la columna que no se correspondan con la cabecera de ninguna columna puedes usar pandas.Series.get y asignar `NaN` por ejemplo ene estos casos:

```
lambda row: row.get(f'x{row["colum"]}', default=np.nan)
```

Si usas una versión de Python inferior a 3.6 puedes usar `str.format` (`"x{}".format(row["colum"])`) en vez de literales de cadena formateados (`f'x{row["colum"]`):